# FreeNAS: terrible FTP speeds ... what can we do?

Tags: networking, ftp, truenas

We are running FreeNAS 8.2.0 (specs below), and getting extremely slow FTP performance.
We have a 100/70mbps FIOS connection, yet FTP (remote) from the FreeNAS is never more than about 5mbps.

We tested FTP from a Mac as a server, and got around 40mbps, but it only streams for 10 seconds or so, then drops to 0 for a minute before resuming.

We tested with `iperf -c iperf.scottlinux.com -P20` from the FreeNAS and got 60mbps upstream. Same from the Mac. So it seems the network is working fine.

Tried AFP and SMB, but results were worse than FTP.

Is there anything we can do? Do we need a stronger machine?

(Local transfers over LAN go at 800mbps or more, so I know the actual storage [zfs] is fast enough.)

```
System Information
Build: FreeNAS-8.2.0-RELEASE-p1-x64 (r11950)
Platform: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
Memory: 6121MB
Load Average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
```

Comment: Someone on the FreeNAS forum said we should add RAM and upgrade to v9.

Answer (score -1):

If you've already tested the components on the local site and know you can get better performance, you might check your uplink, either on the current site's firewall or router. You might be running into bottleneck issues locally?